# Toggle map scale bar with jquery

Tags: jquery, leaflet

I am trying to toggle my map scale bar using jquery, unchecking the map scale box doesn't turn off the scale bar, but checking turns it on. I am new to jquery but I am not sure what is wrong

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name='featured_ad']").on("change", function() {
    var isChecked = $(this).prop("checked");
    if (isChecked) {
      $(".buttons").show();
    } else {
      $(".buttons").hide();
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name='featured_ad']").change(function() {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
      $("radio").show();
      $("#checksl").prop("checked", true)
      var scaleLine = L.control.scale();
      map.addControl(scaleLine);
    } else {
      map.removeControl(scaleLine);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input name="featured_ad" value="1" type="checkbox"/>Map Scale
  <div id="radio" class="buttons">
    <input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" id="checksl"/>Scale bar<br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I put your code in a snippet and as you can see by the error, `L.control.scale();` L is not defined. Also your HTML seems to be missing a closing div

Comment: @j08691 I believe `L` is the [leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) library. I assume the OP has this included in their code, just omitted it in the snippet.

Comment: It can also be noted that `</input>` is not a valid tag. `<input />` is self-closing and does not have a separate closing tag like a `<div>` or `<p>` does

Comment: @j08691  yes it's leaflet, sorry about that

Comment: @lloyd As this is a leaflet-specific question, I have added the leaflet tag to your question

Comment: I think the issue is that `L.control.scale()` creates a new instance of a control each time you call it. So your `addControl()` and `removeControl()` are referring to 2 separate controls. Try setting your scaleLine variable outside of the change handler and see if that works for you

Comment: @mhodges thank you. that works

Comment: @lloyd Great, I will write up an answer for future viewers. Feel free to accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `L.control.scale()` creates a new instance of a control each time you call it. So your `addControl()` and `removeControl()` are referring to 2 separate instances of the control. By setting your `scaleLine` variable outside of the change handler, you can ensure that you only ever have 1 instance of the control that you are referring to, and then the `.removeControl()` will be able to remove it properly, like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name='featured_ad']").on("change", function() {
    var isChecked = $(this).prop("checked");
    if (isChecked) {
      $(".buttons").show();
    } else {
      $(".buttons").hide();
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  // set outside of the change handler so we don't get a new instance every time
  // the checkbox is changed
  var scaleLine = L.control.scale();
  $("input[name='featured_ad']").change(function() {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
      $("radio").show();
      $("#checksl").prop("checked", true);
      // add the control instance
      map.addControl(scaleLine);
    } else {
      // remove the control instance
      map.removeControl(scaleLine);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input name="featured_ad" value="1" type="checkbox" />Map Scale
  <div id="radio" class="buttons">
    <input type="radio" name="ad_pack_id" id="checksl" />Scale bar<br/>
  </div>
</div>
```